# python error FPDF object has no attribute 'y'

Tags: python, save, qgis

I try to make save as button in plugin QGIS Dufour 2.01 and want to save it as pdf file
when i try save my file ( open file destination and then click save ) i got a error message

This code i wrote

```
def _save(self, simpan):
        import fpdf
        # Portrait, millimeter units, A4 page size     
        pdf=fpdf.FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")
        # Set font: Times, normal, size 10
        pdf.set_font('Times','', 12)
        # Layout cell: 0 x 5 mm, text, no border, Left
        pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 1 : ' +  self.ui.lineInput1.text(),border=0,align="L")
        pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 2 : ' + self.ui.lineInput2.text(), border=0,align="L")
        pdf.cell(0,5,'Recomendation : ' + self.ui.textRec2.toPlainText(), border=0, align="L")
        pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 1 :' +  self.ui.lineCond1.text(), border=0, align="L" )
        pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 2 :' + self.ui.lineCond2.text(), border=0, align="L" )
        pdf.output( simpan+'.pdf','F')
```

Error message i get

```
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 615, in cell
    if(self.y+h>self.page_break_trigger and not self.in_footer and self.accept_page_break()):
AttributeError: 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'y'
Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

i use fpdf 1.7 and install it with .msi installer

Comment: That's not the entire traceback, is it? It would help to know which line of _your_ code is triggering the problem…

Comment: um.. i think the problem triggered because some error in fpdf.py script, but i will edit it soon

Comment: If you really think there's a bug in fpdf, then you should be reporting a bug against that library's bug tracker, not asking a question here. If you think it might be caused by you not using fpdf properly, then you have to show us the traceback, so which can see which line of your code called that line of fpdf code (and what else happened on the stack in between).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not added a page to your pdf, before populating it with cells.

Try calling pdf.add_page() just after pdf=fpdf.FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")

Answer (score 0):

add a page

```
def _save(self, simpan):
    import fpdf
    # Portrait, millimeter units, A4 page size     
    pdf=fpdf.FPDF("P", "mm", "A4")
    # add a page 
    pdf.add_page()
    # Set font: Times, normal, size 10
    pdf.set_font('Times','', 12)
    # Layout cell: 0 x 5 mm, text, no border, Left
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 1 : ' +  self.ui.lineInput1.text(),border=0,align="L")
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Input 2 : ' + self.ui.lineInput2.text(), border=0,align="L")
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Recomendation : ' + self.ui.textRec2.toPlainText(), border=0, align="L")
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 1 :' +  self.ui.lineCond1.text(), border=0, align="L" )
    pdf.cell(0,5,'Data 2 :' + self.ui.lineCond2.text(), border=0, align="L" )
    pdf.output( simpan+'.pdf','F')`
```